# Skew symmetric operator on tangent space

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

So I'm studying a paper and there is the following tensor field defined for vector fields on a Riemannian Manifold

$T_EF = H\nabla_{VE}VF + V\nabla_{VE}HF$

where $H,V$ are the projections to the horizontal and vertical subspaces for a given submersion $\pi: M\to B$.

The paper states that $T_E$ is a skew symmetric operator at each point. So I want to proof this, but have some difficulties doing so.
I guess what I have to show is that

$g((T_EF)_p, G_p) = - g(F_p, (T_EG)_p)$ for $p \in M, E,F,G$ vector fields.

But how do I show that the covariant derivative "flips" to the other side ?

Comment: Well I tried a bit further and found the Koszul formula very useful. I'm not 100% sure if my approach is correct but I think it's basically an application of Koszuls formula. Would be great if anyone could confirm that.

Comment: I don't see how the Koszul formula is needed here; it looks like this just follows from the compatibility of $\nabla$ with the metric.$$g(\nabla_U X,Y)=\nabla_U(g(X,Y))-g(X,\nabla_UY)$$

Comment: Well yes you're right. That's what I used too. I don't know why I wrote Koszul formula.